# .Net use WSDL for other communication protocol (TCP, etc)

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to generate a proxy class from WSDL and use the proxy class for other communication protocol?

For example, my application generate the new proxy class and then use this class as a standard for sending request and receiving response messages on TCP, JMS, etc.

Thanks

Comment: @Chen: Proxy class is used to interact(TX/RX) with web service. What do you mean when you say, *standard for sending request and receiving response messages on TCP, JMS, etc*? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use  [WSDL to Proxy Class Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx) to generate proxy from WSDL.